# Вывод ошибок в система Laravel

Tags: laravel

Как сделать вывод ошибок в коде как в laravel 5.6
У меня стоит laravel 5.5 вот с таким выводом ошибок(если в коде допущена ошибка).
http://prntscr.com/jh26qs
Нужно сделать вывод ошибок, как в версии 5.6, как это сделать не переходя на 5.6
http://prntscr.com/jh25rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пакет называется [filp/whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops).

Есть [инструкция](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Exceptions), как интегрировать данный пакет в laravel 5.

Но нужен PHP7.1+